# application unfortunately stopped in doInBackground()

Tags: android

The application crashed suddenly. The logcat says that there is an error in `doInBackground()`. Please help.

Code

```
private class regjson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in prExecute",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;   
}
return "All Done!";
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Post Execute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and here is how i executed it

```
try{
new regjson().execute("hello");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: Don't post a question about a failure without **posting the actual error message as part of its stack trace**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant show a `Toast` in `doInBackground()`.YOu cant update the UI from `doInBackground()`, instaed you have to do it in `onPostExecute()`.

Read more about it in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

So, you have to remove

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

from your code.

If you are using this Toast for debugging purposes you can use `Log.d()` like,

```
Log.d("Key","in Background");
```

And you can see this Log message in your Logcat.

Comment: remove all the Toasts inside doInBackground(), both, inside try and catch block..

Comment: Thanks it resolved the issue of unfortunate stop ...... but my code still not works......:(

Comment: May be some other error...please mark the answer as accepted and post it as a new question..